# Use an "external" variable in React to remember a value between different render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, design-patterns

I'm learning React. I have a counter that auto-increment. The user can cancel with  a button the counter component and with the same button can re-render the component and in this case I want that the Counter resume from the previuos value. I resolved with a counterInitial variable that is a global variable (exactly a private variable because it's inside a module).
I would know if this is a correct pattern or I should use an alternative technique.

This is **Counter.js**:

```
import React from 'react';
let counterInitial =0; 
export default class Counter extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state={count:counterInitial};
        console.log("Sono nel costruttore qui")
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        let self=this;
        requestAnimationFrame(function run(){
            self.timerId=setTimeout(()=>{self.setState({count:self.state.count+1});self.animaFrame=requestAnimationFrame(run)},1000);
        })
    }

    componentWillUnmount(){
        clearTimeout(this.timerId);
        cancelAnimationFrame(this.animaFrame);
    }

    

    render() {
        counterInitial = this.state.count;
        return (
            <p>Valore contatore: {this.state.count}</p>
        )
    }
}
```

This is **CounterController.js**

```
import { useState } from "react"
import Counter from "./Counter"

export default function CounterController(){
    const [contatoreRunning,setContatoreRunning]=useState(true);
    const changeCounterState = ()=>{
        setContatoreRunning(!contatoreRunning);
    }
    return (
        <>
        <button onClick={changeCounterState}>{contatoreRunning?"Stop":"Avvia"}</button>
        {contatoreRunning && <Counter />}
        
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: what you are doing is an anti-pattern. You either need to lift the `counterInital` state up or use a store

Comment: @ilkerkaran I asked here because I supposed was an anti-pattern too. If you could show me how to do could be appreciated.

Comment: your question is too broad. There are many ways to do it. which is why I gave you some keywords so you could make your search and pick whichever solution suits your needs best

Comment: @ilkerkaran I refactorized the code without a global variable. Is this a better version and is ok in React?

Comment: It looks great. You can add that as an answer instead of editing your question tho. the refactor you made is called `lifting state up` as you can view more examples here: https://react.dev/learn/sharing-state-between-components#lifting-state-up-by-example

Answer (score 0):

@ilkerkaran suggested me that my code is an anti-pattern. This is a refactoring version of the code:

CounterController.js:

```
import { useState } from "react"
import Counter from "./Counter"

export default function CounterController(){
    const [contatoreRunning,setContatoreRunning]=useState(true);
    const [stateInitial,setStateInitial]=useState(0);
    const changeCounterState = ()=>{
        setContatoreRunning(!contatoreRunning);
    }
    return (
        <>
        <button onClick={changeCounterState}>{contatoreRunning?"Stop":"Avvia"}</button>
        {contatoreRunning && <Counter initialState={stateInitial} setInitialState={setStateInitial}/>}
        
        </>
    )
}
```

Counter.js

```
import React from 'react';
export default class Counter extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state={count:props.initialState};
        console.log("Sono nel costruttore qui")
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        let self=this;
        requestAnimationFrame(function run(){
            self.timerId=setTimeout(()=>{self.setState({count:self.state.count+1});self.animaFrame=requestAnimationFrame(run)},1000);
        })
    }

    componentWillUnmount(){
        clearTimeout(this.timerId);
        cancelAnimationFrame(this.animaFrame);
        this.props.setInitialState(this.state.count);
    }

    

    render() {
        return (
            <p>Valore contatore: {this.state.count}</p>
        )
    }
}
```

Here the idea is to keep the initial value of the counter in the parent Component (CounterController) and set it in the child (Counter.js). For this purpose I pass the initialState and setInitialState from parent to child Component (this pattern is called *lifting state up*)